# Why variable always returning undefined in the '.find'?

Tags: angular, typescript

I really don't know why my variable is aways returning undefined.

So the problem is basically that the 'schoolAndGradeLevelId' always return undefined... I'm trying to do a function that push students information to a variable, and later this variable will be used to send the info to my API to create these students in the database. If someone can help me, I'd be grateful!

```
  public onFileSelected(files: Array<File>): void {
    if (files.length === 1) {
      this.file = files[0];
      this.loadFile();
      this.fileError = null;
    } else {
      this.file = null;
      this.fileError = 'Selecione apenas um arquivo';
    }
  }

  private fetchShcoolAndGradeLevelId(
    schoolName: string,
    gradeLevelName: string
  ): void {
    const query = this.queriesHandler.handle(
      new GetSchoolAndGradeLevelIdByNameQuery(schoolName, gradeLevelName)
    );
    query.subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        this.schoolAndGradeLevelIds.push({
          ...res.data[0],
          schoolName,
          gradeLevelName,
        });
      },
    });
  }

  private loadFile(): void {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(this.file);
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
      const excel = <string>fileReader.result;
      const rawStudents = parseImportedStudents(excel);
      rawStudents.forEach((student) => {
        let schoolAndGradeLevelId = this.schoolAndGradeLevelIds.find(
          (s) =>
            s.schoolName == student.schoolName &&
            s.gradeLevelName == student.gradeLevelName
        );
        if (!schoolAndGradeLevelId) {
          this.fetchShcoolAndGradeLevelId(
            student.schoolName,
            student.gradeLevelName
          );
          schoolAndGradeLevelId = this.schoolAndGradeLevelIds.find(
            (s) =>
              s.schoolName == student.schoolName &&
              s.gradeLevelName == student.gradeLevelName
          );
        }
        this.students.push({
          studentName: student.studentName,
          gradeLevelName: student.gradeLevelName,
          schoolName: student.schoolName,
          documentNumber: student.documentNumber,
          birthDate: student.birthDate,
          schoolId: schoolAndGradeLevelId?.schoolId,
          gradeLevelId: schoolAndGradeLevelId?.gradeLevelId,
        });
      });
    };
  }

  public onSave(): void {
    const data: ICreateMultipleStudentsRequest = {
      students: this.students.map((student) => {
        return {
          studentName: student.studentName,
          gradeLevelName: student.gradeLevelName,
          schoolName: student.schoolName,
          schoolId: student.schoolId,
          gradeLevelId: student.gradeLevelId,
          documentNumber: student.documentNumber,
          birthDate: student.birthDate,
        };
      }),
    };
    const command = new CreateMultipleStudentsCommand(data);
    this.commandsHandler.handle(command).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.toast.showSuccess('Estudantes importados com sucesso');
        this.hideSpinner();
        this.dialog.hide();
        this.studentsImported.emit();
      },
      (err) => {
        this.toast.showError(err.error?.errorMessage);
        this.hideSpinner();
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Since `fetchShcoolAndGradeLevelId()` is an observable, the data in `this.schoolAndGradeLevelIds` doesn't become available for your `.find()` method in `loadFile()`. You need to call `fetchShcoolAndGradeLevelId()` before  `loadFile()`, ideally once `fetchShcoolAndGradeLevelId()` has completed executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i did to solve this problem was basically this:

```
public loadFile(): void {
let fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.readAsBinaryString(this.file);
fileReader.onload = (e) => {
  const excel = <string>fileReader.result;
  const rawStudents = parseImportedStudents(excel);
  rawStudents.forEach((student) => {
    this.students.push({
      studentName: student.studentName,
      gradeLevelName: student.gradeLevelName,
      schoolName: student.schoolName,
      documentNumber: student.documentNumber,
      birthDate: student.birthDate,
    });
  });
};
fileReader.onloadend = (s) => {
  this.students.forEach((student) => {
    let schoolAndGradeLevelId = this.schoolAndGradeLevelIds.find(
      (s) =>
        s.schoolName == student.schoolName &&
        s.gradeLevelName == student.gradeLevelName
    );
    if (!schoolAndGradeLevelId) {
      const query = this.queriesHandler.handle(
        new GetSchoolAndGradeLevelIdByNameQuery(
          student.schoolName,
          student.gradeLevelName
        )
      );
      query.subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          this.schoolAndGradeLevelIds.push({
            ...res.data[0],
            schoolName: student.schoolName,
            gradeLevelName: student.gradeLevelName,
          });
          student.schoolId = res.data[0]?.schoolId;
          student.gradeLevelId = res.data[0]?.gradeLevelId;    
        },
      });
    } else {
      student.schoolId = schoolAndGradeLevelId?.schoolId;
      student.gradeLevelId = schoolAndGradeLevelId?.gradeLevelId;
    }
  });
};
```

}